# heroku 3.1.0 - C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164:in `spawn': No such file or directory - open (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I just installed the latest Heroku Toolbelt (3.1.0) on my Windows 7/64 PC.

I opened a new Command Line and typed 'heroku login'.
I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Frédéric>heroku login
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164:in `spawn': No such file or directory - open (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164:in `background_update!'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:144:in `inject_libpath'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'
```

I'm stuck right at the first command :(

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3):

1) Open the updater.rb file from ur editor (sublime text 2 here)

2) Remove line 144, which is "background_update!".

After that I simpled typed "heroku login" and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, which I resolved by adding my own brutal update... i deleted the problem from the source and it actually works fine ! :D

I faced the same issue trying to port my code from Win7 to Win8, which caused me to reinstall pretty much everything, and I couldn't get heroku working. Here's what i did :

1°) Open the  updater.rb file from ur editor (sublime text 2 here)
2°) Remove line 144, which is "  inject_libpath! "  if I recall correctly.
3°) I also removed what's in the else statement, line 164. Thought that wasn't sufficient, it only worked after I deleted line 144. Maybe that's where the real problem comes from.

Anyway, after that I simpled typed "heroku" and it magicaly...worked.

By the way, I also had a problem typing heroku keys:add, which I fixed by creating my own key from the Git Batch Promptcommand, following this :

```
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys
```

and then the heroku keys:add command worked perfectly and I could git push heroku master again !

Good luck with Windows8.

Answer (score 2):

It was caused by username being not in latin

It works only with windows user on latin!

see this 
https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/798

Answer (score 0):

If the `.heroku` folder in the user directory i.e. `C:\Users\User_Name\\.heroku` is set to hidden, this error is thrown when any `Heroku` command is used.

Manually unhide this and others related files using the file explorer, and the issue should be
fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the line

```
log_path = File.join(Heroku::Helpers.home_directory, '.heroku', 'autoupdate.log')
```

You have to replace `Heroku::Helpers.home_directory` by a string containing the short filename of your personal folder. To get it, open a command line (cmd.exe, not Git Bash) ensure that you are in your personal folder, and type :

```
cd ..
dir /x
```

Then you will find the short name in a format like `XXX~1`.

So replace `Heroku::Helpers.home_directory` by `'C:\Users\XXX~1'` and all will work properly.